# How do you get nicely formatted results from an Oracle procedure that returns a reference cursor?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

In MS SQL Server if I want to check the results from a Stored procedure I might execute the following in Management Studio.

```
--SQL SERVER WAY
exec sp_GetQuestions('OMG Ponies')
```

The output in the results pane might look like this.

```
ID    Title                                             ViewCount   Votes 
----- ------------------------------------------------- ---------- --------
2165  Indexed View vs Indexes on Table                  491         2  
5068  SQL Server equivalent to Oracle’s NULLS FIRST     524         3 
1261  Benefits Of Using SQL Ordinal Position Notation?  377         2 

(3 row(s) affected)
```

No need to write loops or PRINT statements.

To do the same thing in Oracle I might execute the following anonymous block in SQL Developer

```
--ORACLE WAY
    DECLARE
        OUTPUT  MYPACKAGE.refcur_question;
        R_OUTPUT MYPACKAGE.r_question;
        USER    VARCHAR2(20);

BEGIN

  dbms_output.enable(10000000);
  USER:= 'OMG Ponies';
  recordCount := 0;



  MYPACKAGE.GETQUESTIONS(p_OUTPUT => OUTPUT, 
  p_USER=> USER, 

  ) ;




  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID |  Title | ViewCount | Votes' );

  LOOP 
    FETCH OUTPUT
    INTO R_OUTPUT;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(R_OUTPUT.QUESTIONID || '|' || R_OUTPUT.TITLE 
               '|' || R_OUTPUT.VIEWCOUNT '|' || R_OUTPUT.VOTES);
          recordCount := recordCount+1;




 EXIT WHEN OUTPUT % NOTFOUND;  
      END LOOP;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record Count:'||recordCount);
      CLOSE OUTPUT;


    END;
```

This outputs like

```
ID|Title|ViewCount|Votes 
2165|Indexed View vs Indexes on Table|491|2  
5068|SQL Server equivalent to Oracle’s NULLS FIRST|524|3 
1261|Benefits Of Using SQL Ordinal Position Notation?|377|2 
Record Count: 3
```

So the SQL version has 1 line and the oracle has 18 and the output is ugly. Its exacerbated if there are a lot of columns and/or the data is numeric.

What's odd to me about this is that if I write this statement in either SQL Developer or Management studio...

```
SELECT 
ID, 
Title, 
ViewCount, 
Votes
FROM votes where user = 'OMG Ponies'
```

The results are fairly similar. This makes me feel like I'm either missing a technique or using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If `GetQuestions` is a function returning a refcursor, which seems to be what you have in the SQL Server version, then rather you may be able to do something like this:

```
select * from table(MyPackage.GetQuestions('OMG Ponies'));
```

Or if you need it in a PL/SQL block then you can use the same select in a cursor.

You can also have the function produce the `dbms_output` statements instead so they're always available for debugging, although that adds a little overhead.

**Edit**

Hmmm, not sure it's possible to `cast()` the returned refcursor to a usable type, unless you're willing to declare your own type (and a table of that type) outside the package. You can do this though, just to dump the results:

```
create package mypackage as
    function getquestions(user in varchar2) return sys_refcursor;
end mypackage;
/

create package body mypackage as
    function getquestions(user in varchar2) return sys_refcursor as
        r sys_refcursor;
    begin
        open r for
            /* Whatever your real query is */
            select 'Row 1' col1, 'Value 1' col2 from dual
            union
            select 'Row 2', 'Value 2' from dual
            union
            select 'Row 3', 'Value 3' from dual;
            return r;
    end;
end mypackage;
/

var r refcursor;
exec :r := mypackage.getquestions('OMG Ponies');
print r;
```

And you can use the result of the call in another procedure or function; it's just getting to it outside PL/SQL that seems to be a little tricky.

**Edited to add:** With this approach, if it's a procedure you can do essentially the same thing:

```
var r refcursor;
exec mypackage.getquestions(:r, 'OMG Ponies');
print r;
```

Comment: The SQL Server version probably is not a function. In SQL Server, stored procedures that return set like results just have `select` statements that are not bound to a cursor. Getting the results of the execution of such a stored procedure is the same as getting the results from a `select` query on the client side.

Comment: I should learn about SQL Server one day. Seems like the equivalent would be a function that returns a refcursor though, rather than a procedure with an `OUT` parameter, so it can be used in a query from plan SQL?

Comment: MyPackage.GetQuestions is a procedure. e.g. PROCEDURE GETQUETSIONS(output      IN OUT MYPACKAGE.refcur_question, user IN VARCHAR2). When I tied your technique I get invalid identifier errors

Comment: I was thinking you could make it a function instead; `FUNCTION GETQUESTIONS(user IN VARCHAR2) RETURNS refcur_question`. But you may not be able to modify it; and from memory you might have to define the return type (`refcur_question`) at schema level, not inside the package, but it's been a while...

Comment: If you are keeping the existing procedure, try `exec mypackage.getquestions(:r, 'OMG Ponies');` instead of having the extra function to do the conversion. I'd fixated on a function because I thought it would cast, but as it doesn't a procedure is fine (and possibly more 'standard'). So you still have 3 lines replacing your original 18 *8-)

Comment: Alex that worked and what I was looking for but the function was interesting as well

Comment: If it's a function you don't even need a variable, just `select mypackage.getquestions('OMG Ponies') from dual;`

Answer (score 3):

SQL Developer automatically catches the output from running your stored procedures. Running the stored procedure directly from our procedure editor, you can see this behavior detailed in my post here

[SQL Developer Tip: Viewing REFCURSOR Output](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/12/sql-developer-tip-viewing-refcursor-output/)

Now, if you want to run the refcursor as part of an anon block in our SQL Worksheet, you could do something similar to this

```
var rc refcursor
exec :rc := GET_EMPS(30)
print rc
```

--where GET_EMPS() would be your sp_GetQuestions('OMG Ponies') call. The PRINT command sends the output from the 'query' which is ran via the stored procedure, and looks like this:

```
anonymous block completed
RC
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 EMAIL                     PHONE_NUMBER         HIRE_DATE                 JOB_ID     SALARY     COMMISSION_PCT MANAGER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID 
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -------------------- ------------------------- ---------- ---------- -------------- ---------- ------------- 
114         Den                  Raphaely                  DRAPHEAL                  515.127.4561         07-DEC-94 12.00.00        PU_MAN     11000                     100        30            
115         Alexander            Khoo                      AKHOO                     515.127.4562         18-MAY-95 12.00.00        PU_CLERK   3100                      114        30            
116         Shelli               Baida                     SBAIDA                    515.127.4563         24-DEC-97 12.00.00        PU_CLERK   2900                      114        30            
117         Sigal                Tobias                    STOBIAS                   515.127.4564         24-JUL-97 12.00.00        PU_CLERK   2800                      114        30            
118         Guy                  Himuro                    GHIMURO                   515.127.4565         15-NOV-98 12.00.00        PU_CLERK   2600                      114        30            
119         Karen                Colmenares                KCOLMENA                  515.127.4566         10-AUG-99 12.00.00        PU_CLERK   2500                      114        30
```

Now, you said 10g. If you're in 12c, we have enhanced the PL/SQL engine to support implicit cursor results. So this gets a bit easier, no more setting up the cursor, you just make a call to get the data, as documented here:
 http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/migr_tools_feat.htm#DRDAA230

Comment: I was actually looking at this feature yesterday. It's nice but kind of a PIA to get to in that I can't just open a "Run PL/SQL" window Thanks for the 12c tip. We're still on 11G so I look forward to using it eventually. Also I fixed up the formatting of your post. See [Editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how I did it

Comment: So you want a 'run PL/SQL' window that will auto-grab the output, like our Procedure Editor offers when executing a single unit? Not a bad idea...I'll kick it around the group and see where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
    Create Sample Package in HR Schema
*/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PRINT_REF_CURSOR
AS
    PROCEDURE SP_S_EMPLOYEES_BY_DEPT (
        p_DEPARTMENT_ID   IN  INTEGER,
        Out_Cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR); 

END PRINT_REF_CURSOR;        

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PRINT_REF_CURSOR
AS

    PROCEDURE SP_S_EMPLOYEES_BY_DEPT (
        p_DEPARTMENT_ID   IN  INTEGER,
        Out_Cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    AS 
    BEGIN
      OPEN Out_Cur FOR
           SELECT *
             FROM EMPLOYEES
             WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = p_DEPARTMENT_ID;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('SP_S_EMPLOYEES_BY_DEPT' || ',' || '-20000' || ',' );
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('SP_S_EMPLOYEES_BY_DEPT' || ',' || '-20001' || ',' );    
    END SP_S_EMPLOYEES_BY_DEPT;         

END PRINT_REF_CURSOR;    

/*
    Fetch values using Ref Cursor and display it in grid.
*/

var RC refcursor;

DECLARE 
    p_DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER;
    OUT_CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN 
  p_DEPARTMENT_ID := 90;
  OUT_CUR := NULL;

  PRINT_REF_CURSOR.SP_S_EMPLOYEES_BY_DEPT ( p_DEPARTMENT_ID, OUT_CUR);
  :RC := OUT_CUR;

END;
/
PRINT RC;  
/************************************************************************/
```