# What is the standard way to return records from an Oracle function?

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I really avoided the "best" word for my question but it really is the most suitable word for it.

What's the best(most efficient) way of returning records from a function?

Currently I have something like:

```
  FUNCTION myFunct(param1 VARCHAR2) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS
    myCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    OPEN myCursor FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE field = param1;

    RETURN(myCursor);
  END myFunct;
```

I can run this fine but with everything else I am reading like (TABLE type, implicit cursor, etc) I am really confused about what is most suitable.

P.S. how can I loop over this cursor after I call it from a proc?

EDIT:
I've read that I can only iterate through cursors ONCE (forums.oracle.com/thread/888365) but in reality I want to loop contents several times. Does this mean that I am opt to use associative arrays instead?

Comment: It depends on the use case.  Are you returning the data to a client application?  In your real code, are you doing something that requires PL/SQL?  If not, why not use a view?  Are you writing a multi-stage ETL process?  It would be rather unusual to return a `REF CURSOR` to another piece of PL/SQL.

Comment: This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125992/how-to-return-a-refcursor-from-oracle-function

Comment: @JustinCave - " It would be rather unusual to return a REF CURSOR to another piece of PL/SQL".  Would it?  Ref cursors give us programmatic control over a result set, using static or dynamic SQL.  It doesn't strike me as unusual that we might want to encapsulate that programmatic control inside a discrete function, especially if the logic is complicated.  Plus there's the normal use case: we have several different pieces of code which all need to read the result set.

Comment: This link contains examples how to read from ref cursor returned from a procedure in another pl/sql proc, ado recordset and java: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php

Comment: @APC - If you can return a ref cursor, it would seem highly probable that you could create a view instead and just apply predicates to the view rather than pass parameters to the function.  A view seems more flexible if you need to do something in the future like join it to another table.  There are certainly cases where we want to use dynamic SQL or return the result of different queries from a function depending on various conditions.  But those would be the exceptional cases in my mind, not the common cases.

Comment: @JustinCave A function which return `REF CURSOR` has another advantage   citing my example, I have a function which returns `sys_refcursor` and one strong reason I am using because I can `order by` in my function. Whereas in a view I wouldn't be using `order by` clause in view sql structure.

Comment: I am currently reading about assiociative arrays. What I failed to mention is that the returned list is just basically a list of string. Does this make any changes to your suggestions?

Comment: I've read that I can only iterate through cursors ONCE (https://forums.oracle.com/thread/888365) but in reality I want to loop contents several times. Does this mean that I am opt to use associative arrays instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE example_pkg AS

    /*
    ** Record and nested table for "dual" table
    ** It is global, you can use it in other packages
    */
    TYPE g_dual_ntt IS TABLE OF SYS.DUAL%ROWTYPE;
    g_dual  g_dual_ntt;

    /*
    ** procedure is public. You may want to use it in different parts of your code
    */
    FUNCTION myFunct(param1 VARCHAR2) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;

    /*
    ** Example to work with a cursor
    */
    PROCEDURE example_prc;

END example_pkg;

create or replace 
PACKAGE BODY example_pkg AS

    FUNCTION myFunct(param1 VARCHAR2) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
    AS
        myCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
        OPEN myCursor FOR
            SELECT  dummy
            FROM    dual
            WHERE   dummy = param1;

        RETURN(myCursor);
    END myFunct;

    PROCEDURE example_prc
    AS
        myCursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
        l_dual   g_dual_ntt; /* With bulk collect there is no need to initialize the collection */
    BEGIN
        -- Open cursor
        myCursor := myFunct('X');
        -- Fetch from cursor  /  all at onece
        FETCH myCursor BULK COLLECT INTO l_dual;
        -- Close cursor
        CLOSE myCursor;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Print: ');
        FOR indx IN 1..l_dual.COUNT LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('element: ' || l_dual(indx).dummy );
        END LOOP;
    END example_prc;

END example_pkg;

EXECUTE example_pkg.example_prc();

/*
Print: 
element: X
*/
```

Please take a look at this link: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php

You might find it useful...

Comment: Accepted as answer (sole answer). Thank you, and for the link also.

Comment: @Kampai There is no one proper way to work with cursors (SYS_REFCURSOR). You can return it from a function or set as variable. It is up to you. The main reason to use it is you might want to open it for different queries, i.e.: different where conditions.