# C# pl/sql package-function

Tags: c#, plsql

```
public List<MuseumDto> GetMuseumsByName(string museum_Name)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.
      ConnectionStrings["OracleConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    var museum = new List<MuseumDto>();
    using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OracleCommand mycom = new OracleCommand();
        connection.Open();
        mycom.CommandText = "museum_package.get_MuseumByName";
        mycom.Connection = connection;
        mycom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        mycom.Parameters.Add("v_museum", museum_Name);

        OracleParameter returnParameteraram = mycom.Parameters.Add("ReturnValue", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
        returnParameteraram.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        OracleDataReader reader = mycom.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                museum.Add(new MuseumDto
                {
                    museumId = reader.GetInt32(0),
                    name = reader.GetString(1),
                    city = reader.GetString(2),
                    about= reader.GetString(3),
                    schedule = reader.GetString(4),
                    noArtefacts= reader.GetInt32(5),

                });
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
    return museum;
}
```

This is the table definition:

```
create table museum
( museumid     number(5) not null
, name         varchar2(30)
, city         varchar2(30)
, about        varchar2(200)
, schedule     varchar2(40)
, noartefacts  number(3) );
```

and here is my function:

```
create or replace package body museum_package as

    function get_MuseumByName
        ( v_museum Museum.Name%type )
        return sys_refcursor
    is
        v_cursor sys_refcursor;
        v_museumName museum.name%type := '%' || v_museum || '%';
    begin
        open v_cursor for
            select museumID, name, city, about, schedule, noArtefacts
            from   museum 
            where  name like v_museumName;

        return v_cursor;
    end;

end museum_package;
```

I'm receiving an exception:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_MUSEUMBYNAME'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: ORA-06550 usually means something wrong with your PL/sql function.what does  Museum.Name%type  means?

Comment: @Hameed, `Museum.Name%type` instructs the PL/SQL compiler to anchor the function parameter to the datatype of the table column, probably a `varchar2` in this case. `PLS-00306` means the function wan't called with the expected parameters.

Comment: is a variable same as Museum.name field from table, what exactly are you asking? :) @Hameed

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Museum.Name%type so is a type from the current tables column if I can understand that,but how can .net compiler deduce the type.may be the OP's user need to specify  the data type explicitly?

Comment: @Hameed I don't know C# but it appears to declare `museum_Name` as a string, which should be OK unless there is more to it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment in another people's posts as I don't have enough reputation (I'm new around here). Your problem may be because .NET can't map the types of the columns in Oracle with the ones you specified while reading the columns.

Could you please show us the data types of the columns of the museum table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE MUSEUM(MuseumId NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
NAme VARCHAR(30), CITY VARCHAR(30), About VARCHAR(200)
, SCHEDULE VARCHAR(40), NoArtefacts NUMBER(3));

Comment: I noticed your command type is set to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and you are using a function. Is there a command type for functions? Also, you could try to change the parameter type of the function from `Museum.Name%type` to `VARCHAR` just to give it a try. I would also try to change the function into a procedure.

Comment: Is storedProcedure for functions too, i will try to change it but i don't think it will solve my problem :(

Comment: I came across this Stack Overflow question. Maybe it's just what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535405/execute-an-oracle-function-that-returns-a-reference-cursor-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Return value must be added as first parameter.

```
 OracleParameter returnParameteraram = mycom.Parameters.Add("ReturnValue", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
 returnParameteraram.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
mycom.Parameters.Add("v_museum", museum_Name);
```