# Oracle Package creation error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I created a package and a package body as below:

```
Create or replace Package pkg_1
as
procedure main(param1 varchar2, param2 varchar2, param3 int);
procedure one(param1 varchar2, param2 varchar2);
procedure two(param1 varchar2, param2 varchar2);
end pkg_1;
/

create or replace package body pkg_1
as
procedure main (param1 varchar2, param2 varchar2, param3 int)
is
v_sql_script varchar2(1000);
begin
case param3
when 1 then
v_sql_script := 'begin exec pkg_1.one(:param1,:param2); end;';
execute immediate v_sql_script using param1, param2;
end case;
end;
```

Now when I execute the package procedure with following statement:

```
exec pkg_1.main('p1','p2',1);

I got the following error:

ORA-06550: line 1, column 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PKG_1" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "PKG_1" to continue.
```

Can someone please suggest me what I have done wrong here?

Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you're executing it inside a PL/SQL block, in which case you do not need the `exec`. Just do `pkg_1.main('p1','p2',1);` on its own.

Quite similar to part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991721/run-stored-procedure-in-sql-developer/3992244#3992244).