# SQL syntax error in creating spatial network

Tags: sql, oracle, networking, spatial, oracle-spatial

I am trying to create a spatial network from a shapefile (representing street centrelines) imported into an Oracle DB with FME Desktop. The 'CENTRELINES' spatial object contains a GEOM column that I'd like to use as the basis for a network analysis to allocate ambulance facilities (points) among retirement homes (points) based on route distance as a cost attribute. Any advice on methodology for approaching this morbid problem in Oracle Spatial would be welcome, but the main issue is that I am a beginner at SQL. I've used Oracle's [documentation](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/appdev.101/b10828/sdo_net_ref.htm#CHDJADJI) to compose the following SQL statement:

```
-- create an LRS geometry network
EXEC SDO_NET.CREATE_LRS_NETWORK(
  'LRS_net', -- network name
  'CENTRELINES', -- LRS geometry table name
  'GEOM', -- LRS geometry column name
  1, -- number of hierarchy levels
  FALSE, -- directed link?
  TRUE -- node with cost?
  );
```

The script outputs the following:

```
Error starting at line 2 in command:
EXEC SDO_NET.CREATE_LRS_NETWORK(
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 34:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   ( ) - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   table continue avg count current exists max min prior sql
   stddev sum variance execute multiset the both leading
   trailing forall merge year month day hour minute second
   timezone_hour timezone_minute timezone_region timezone_abbr
   time timestamp interval date
   <a string literal with character set specification>
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

...

Error starting at line 9 in command:
)
Error report:
Unknown Command
```

I understand that line 2 is producing the error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following...
```

Given that semi-colons are required to end an SQL query, why is this a problem?

EDIT: The following script produced the network by adding begin/end:

```
begin
SDO_NET.CREATE_LRS_NETWORK(
  'LRS_net', 
  'CENTRELINES', 
  'GEOM', 
  1, 
  FALSE, 
  TRUE);
end;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I added the begin/end syntax:

Comment: You need to add a semicolon to line 8.  Change `TRUE)` to `TRUE);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm#sthref1585), the SQL*Plus `execute` command normally has to be entered on one line:

> If your EXECUTE command cannot fit on one line because of the PL/SQL
>   statement, use the SQL*Plus continuation character (a hyphen).

What it's actually trying to run under the hood is a translation as

```
BEGIN
    SDO_NET.CREATE_LRS_NETWORK(;
END;
/
```

... which is (maybe obviously when written like that) not valid PL/SQL. Nothing to do with the spatial call per se. If you do want to split it onto multiple lines, you can just use an explicit `begin`/`end` rather than the shorthand `exec`.

The second problem maybe suggests that you've run the short version more than once, though it isn't a feature I'm very familiar with; but is not related to the initial semi-colon error. (Also, a semi-colon isn't strictly needed to end a *SQL* statement, but that's a detail for another time...).