# Calling an Oracle Stored Procedure with multiple row return from Spring

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures

I am working on an application using Java, Eclipse, and Spring. We have an Oracle database that we are connecting to using JDBC.

Currently the application is using adhoc queries in the application to the database. Most of these were done by people working on the project before I came along. I have decided that using stored procedures is a better way of going. Decouple for another layer of abstraction. Not having to send the sql statement every time so less bandwidth and faster transactions. Oracle can optimize them unlike with the adhoc ones. Changes to them can occur without needing to be recompiled as long as inputs and outputs dont change. All that wonderful stuff.

The adhoc queries frequently get back multiple rows and are using the interface rowMapper and mapRow

```
 return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new adhoc_mapper1());

class adhoc_mapper1 implements RowMapper<List<String>> {
    public List<String> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException{
    ArrayList<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    arr1.add(rs.getString("OUT_POSITION_ID"));
    arr1.add(rs.getString("OUT_POSITION_TITLE_EN"));

    return arr1;
    }
}
```

Adhoc Query in Spring

```
 SELECT     HR.POSITION_ID,     HR.POSITION_TITLE_EN,   HR.POSITION_TITLE_FR,   HR.SECURITY_ID,     HR.GROUP_NAME,  HR.GROUP_LEVEL,     HR.POSITION_IS_ACTIVE
    FROM HR_POSITION HR JOIN DRILL_POSITION DP ON (HR.POSITION_ID = DP.POSITION_ID) 
WHERE DP.TYPEVALUE = RECORD_TYPE;
```

Called Procedure in Oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DOCSADM.DRILL_RECORD_POSITION (
    RECORD_TYPE IN VARCHAR2,
    OUT_POSITION_ID OUT VARCHAR2,
    OUT_POSITION_TITLE_EN OUT VARCHAR2,
    OUT_POSITION_TITLE_FR OUT VARCHAR2,
    OUT_SECURITY_ID OUT VARCHAR2,
    OUT_GROUP_NAME OUT VARCHAR2,
    OUT_GROUP_LEVEL OUT VARCHAR2,
    OUT_POSITION_IS_ACTIVE OUT VARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  HR.POSITION_ID,     HR.POSITION_TITLE_EN,   HR.POSITION_TITLE_FR,   HR.SECURITY_ID,     HR.GROUP_NAME,  HR.GROUP_LEVEL,     HR.POSITION_IS_ACTIVE
    INTO    OUT_POSITION_ID,    OUT_POSITION_TITLE_EN,  OUT_POSITION_TITLE_FR,  OUT_SECURITY_ID,    OUT_GROUP_NAME, OUT_GROUP_LEVEL,    OUT_POSITION_IS_ACTIVE
    FROM HR_POSITION HR JOIN DRILL_POSITION DP ON (HR.POSITION_ID = DP.POSITION_ID) WHERE DP.TYPEVALUE = RECORD_TYPE;
END DRILL_RECORD_POSITION;
```

As you can see, the procedure returns multiple rows. I had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53488987/6891471) about how to view the output from the procedure in Oracle but was not successful.

As the project is not using called procedures I have no examples in the code base to work back from. One of my coworkers involved in a different project has used them and was kind enough to show me their example, which regrettably was not helpful because it only called a procedure and had no returns. Their overall design also appears different. But I saw that they were using SimpleJdbcCall so I started looking online to use that.

**Good examples online that I failed to get working.**

I found examples that were doing what I needed to do, but not quite how I was expecting.

1. [This example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springjdbc/springjdbc_simplejdbccall.htm) goes along the lines of what I was expecting to see and use, except that it only takes a single row as the result and I wasn't able to figure out how to alter the mapping to accept multiple rows.
2. [This example](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch13s05.html) however does use a procedure that returns multiple rows, but it uses ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper and passes in a class.
3. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40984167/6891471) has several ways of doing these calls but are all single row returns, but the answers comments do suggest that its easy to expand for multiple rows. But again I was unable to get it working.

I am not wanting to create a class for every procedure or family of procedures. Most of the queries end up displaying the information in a table, so I have been using a 2d object to hold and then display the data. It has been very convenient so far. I am fine with creating a mapping for each procedure as it needs to be done (unless there is a better way?), but I do not want to create a class for every procedure (and sometimes the mapper as well).

I have 150 lines of failed code attempts which I have not included to keep the question shorter. If they would help then I can include them.

***TL;DR***
I want to call a stored procedure in Oracle from Spring which has multiple rows being returned. I would like to use just the calling function, which either uses the RowMapper method of mapping, or an in function mapping. I want to avoid using class structures of data if possible. I am expecting/hoping it to look and get used like the first code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a basic error with my methodology for this. The way in which I was attempting to return multiple rows is wrong. As pointed out by someone in my linked question. So the ways that I was attempting to access it were also wrong. When I limited the return to a single row the following was successful.

First the imports

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
```

Then the call

```
 final String procedureCall = "{call DRILL_RECORD_POSITION(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}";

      try (Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();) 
      {
          ArrayList<String> inner = new ArrayList<String>();
          CallableStatement callableSt = connection.prepareCall(procedureCall);
          callableSt.setString(1, "D");

          callableSt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
          callableSt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
          callableSt.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
          callableSt.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);
          callableSt.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);
          callableSt.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);
          callableSt.registerOutParameter(8, Types.VARCHAR);

          //Call Stored Procedure
          callableSt.executeUpdate();

          for (int i=2; i<9; i++)
          {
               System.out.println(callableSt.getString(i));
          }
      }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Note that I am using the try with resources so I do not have to worry about closing the connection.

Other mistakes I made during this was not having enough ? in the String which was leading to invalid column index errors. I then made the mistake of trying to get the information before I actually executed the call.