# Using variables in Oracle SQL Developer 3.2

Tags: oracle, variables, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am extremely new to SQL, and manage to extract from some other queries we use the following syntax:

```
--VARIABLES
undefine PF_PROD --product;
undefine PF_PSG --shop;


--QUERY
SELECT *
FROM ET1250
WHERE PRODUCT=&&PF_PROD
AND PRICE_SHOP_GROUP=&&PF_PSG
ORDER BY PERIOD_YEAR desc,PERIOD_WEEK desc;
```

This works fine as long as I run the `undefine` statements first, is there a way to make the query always ask for these variables without me having to `undefine` them first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single `&`. This is covered briefly in the [SQL Developer documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25259_01/appdev.31/e24285/intro.htm#sthref215):

> For substitution variables, the syntax &&variable assigns a permanent
>   variable value, and the syntax &variable assigns a temporary (not
>   stored) variable value.

... and in more detail in the [SQL*Plus documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref464), which is largely relevant for both clients.

Note that if you `define` or `accept` a variable then it won't be prompted for even with a single ampersand, but that doesn't seem to be relevant to you at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of variable in SQL-plus: substitution and bind.

Substitution variables can replace SQL*Plus command options or other hard-coded text:

```
define a = 1;
select &a from dual;
undefine a;
```

Bind variables store data values for SQL and PL/SQL statements executed in the RDBMS; they can hold single values or complete result setsb:

```
var x number;
exec :x := 10;
select :x from dual;
exec select count(*) into :x from from dual;
exec print x;
```

SQL Developer support substitution variables, but when you execute query with bind `:var` syntax you are prompted for binding (in dialog box).

Reference:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/sub-var-087723.html SQL*Plus Substitution Variables, Christopher Jones, 2004
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171706/173149