# Oracle PL/SQL: Find similar records in the table within a sliding 3 sec window

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am looking for a way to identify similar records in the Oracle 11.2 table within a sliding 3 sec window. There are approximately 500K rows in the table inserted within 24 hours period.

Requirements:

1. These records should satisfy a similarity score of at least 88% using UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY
2. The FLAG column should be updated for a given record if there is at least one more similar record exists within three seconds window

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE ADDR_TAB
  ( DT DATE NOT NULL,
    ADDR VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    FLAG INT
  );
CREATE INDEX ADDR_DATE_IDX ON ADDR_TAB(DT);
```

Sample data:

```
insert into addr_tab values (to_date('03-OCT-13 04.36.57 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM'),'test',null);
insert into addr_tab values (to_date('03-OCT-13 04.36.57 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM'),'test123',null);
insert into addr_tab values (to_date('03-OCT-13 04.36.58 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM'),'2test2',null);
insert into addr_tab values (to_date('03-OCT-13 04.36.58 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM'),'12test',null);
insert into addr_tab values (to_date('03-OCT-13 04.37.00 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM'),'12test',null);
insert into addr_tab values (to_date('03-OCT-13 04.37.02 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM'),'12test',null);
insert into addr_tab values (to_date('03-OCT-13 04.37.03 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM'),'1test87',null);
insert into addr_tab values (to_date('03-OCT-13 04.37.03 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM'),'12test',null);
insert into addr_tab values (to_date('03-OCT-13 04.37.03 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM'),'12test56',null);
insert into addr_tab values (to_date('03-OCT-13 04.37.04 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM'),'12test88',null);
insert into addr_tab values (to_date('03-OCT-13 04.37.05 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM'),'12test56',null);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b53f/1

Comment: You described the requirements just fine - now it's time to show us what you tried and where did you get stuck

Comment: To @alfasin: I could only think about looping through the records in multiple passes, but I believe there should be a better way to solve the issue by using the analytic functions from Oracle.

Comment: @Henry, can you show us the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH basedata 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   addr_tab 
         ORDER  BY dt) 
SELECT * 
FROM   basedata A 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   basedata B 
               WHERE  ( ( A.dt <= ( B.dt + 3 / 86400 ) ) 
                        AND ( A.dt >= ( B.dt - 3 / 86400 ) ) ) 
                      AND a.ROWID <> b.ROWID 
                      AND utl_match.Jaro_winkler(A.addr, B.addr) * 100 >= 88)
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b53f/22

Comment: Very interesting solution. Thanks! I have one more follow-up question. Is it possible to modify the query to identify any given number (count) of the similar records within 3 sec window? It is very useful if the threshold changes, which is exactly what happened to me.

Comment: You can definitely parameterize the query. Will update he post when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks again! I will be very interested to see the modified query that uses more generic approach based on a given threshold (number of similar records within 3 sec)

Comment: How are you executing this query? SQL Developer/IDE, SQLPlus .. etc?

Comment: I am running it in SQL Developer

Comment: Take a look at this answer, I have already answered similar question. Will update the answer here shortly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653423/how-do-i-use-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer/5653541#5653541

Comment: Hi @Chandu, could you please upload the updated query (generic version) if you already have one? Thanks!