# How to count select sql data rows and pass value in to the function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This my select p/l sql. `this_select_count` is a row count returned by the select. and `my_fucntion` is p/l sql function for get some value
How can i count my select result and pass that count value in to the `my_function` as pram.

```
SELECT 
   t.NAME,
   my_function(this_select_count) my_value,
   t.ID
FROM view t
```

Comment: Completely out of the zone. Samples please and rephrase your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally unclear (at least to me) from your question *what* you want to count, but if you want to pass the total rowcount returned by the select, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT t.name,
       my_function(count(*) over ()) as my_value,
       t.id
FROM view t;
```

If you need a different count, you will most want to adjust the `over()` part to only count rows for a specific ID or name.

Comment: sorry for my unclear question. i want to pass row count returned by the select. Thanks for you help this really help to me. again thanks lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the count to a variable and use it in the function. Examples are at [How do I use variables in Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653423/how-do-i-use-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer)