# regexp_like expression not working with variable

Tags: oracle

The record has nothing in the errors field. The commented out code doesn't return anything but when the variable is used it returns a record. What am I doing wrong?

```
test varchar(5);
test := '1';
select  * from timedetail 
where empnum = '013061361' and tsdate = '1-nov-13' 
--and  regexp_like(errors, '[1,0]')
and  regexp_like(errors, '[ || test || ]')
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a variable: '[ || test || ]' is a string.
you need this one '[' || test || ']'

Comment: It says Test invalid identifier when I try and run

Comment: But that is due to how you use your parameters. syntax to use parameters in SQL is different for many tools. Oracle SQL Developer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653423/how-do-i-use-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer . SQL*Plus: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm

Comment: I'm not following. I'm using Oracle

Comment: Oracle is DBMS, it is an engine. Question is how you access it? Two standard tools are SQL*Plus and Oracle SQL Developer. But there are also TOAD, PL/SQL Developer, and others. Parameters in SQL are not part of a standard so everyone free to implement them their own way.

Comment: And if this is part of the code in python, c# or another language, you will be using bind variables that are driver specific.

Comment: The query should work the same no matter what front end I am using.

Comment: Something is wrong the the second argument of regexp_like where test is being used

Comment: I'm using sql developer

Comment: To get most of this situation I would go with Oracle SQL Developer syntax (as more common between tools). But is not an universal solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52407/discussion-between-vav-and-user1345246)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle `regexp_like` uses single quotes to delimit the expression. To use a variable you'll need to isolate the regex metacharacters from the variable, so just concatenate the parts to complete the requirement. Use the `'i'` option is to ignore case sensitivity.

Try this:

```
   test varchar(5);
   test := '1';

 select  * from timedetail 
  where empnum = '013061361' 
    and tsdate = '1-nov-13' 
    and  regexp_like(errors, test,'i'); --matches any string containing 1
--and  regexp_like(errors,'^' ||  test,'i') --matches any string beginning 1
--and  regexp_like(errors, test || '$','i') --matches any string ending 1
--and  regexp_like(errors, '^' || test || '$','i') --matches any string exactly 1
```