# declare bind variables in script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, bind-variables

I have script that uses this variables

```
with
TIME_DATA  as ( select $$D:=:DA$$ td from dual),

GROUP_INFO as (select $$N:=:GR_ID$$ gr_id_number from dual),
```

and uses them like this

```
 A_PLUS_TEK as(select point_id, ml_id, ml_name, val a_plus_month, DA
from VALUE_DATA, TIME_DATA
where ml_id = 381 and DA = trunc(td, 'MM'))
```

I want to know how to initialize this variables, now when I run script I have this ouput:

```
Bind Variable "DA$$" is NOT DECLARED
```

**EDIT:** Usually users enter this values on website, I have access only to database, where I got script from reports table. Also I want to know how to initialize this variables from c#.

**EIDT2:** I took this for example ([How do I use variables in Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653423/how-do-i-use-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer)). It works.

```
variable v_count number;
variable v_emp_id number;
exec :v_emp_id := 1234;
exec select count(1) into :v_count from emp;
select *
  from emp
 where empno = :v_emp_id
exec print :v_count;
```

my code:

```
    declare
    variable DA$$ VARCHAR2(80);
    variable gr_id$$ number;
    begin 
    exec :DA$$ := to_date('2011-09-13 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
    exec :gr_id$$ := '1341';
BEGIN
```

and then with statement :

```
   WITH
    TIME_DATA  as ( select $$D:=:DA$$ td from dual),

    GROUP_INFO as (select $$N:=:GR_ID$$ gr_id_number from dual),

 ....
END;
```

But still have this

```
 Bind Variable "DA$$" is NOT DECLARED
anonymous block completed
```

This also change nothing

`exec :DA$$ := '2011-09-13 09:00:00';`

I think that DA$$ is date, because it used in trunc() `DA = trunc(td, 'MM'))` 
When I select Run Statement(trl+Enter), Sql Developer offers to enter bind variables, but I don't know how to enter date.

**EDIT3:** Finally I do this without Declare, Begin, End and it works :

```
    variable DA$$ VARCHAR2(80);
    variable gr_id$$ number; 
    exec :DA$$ := to_date('2011-09-13 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
    exec  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:DA$$);    
    exec :gr_id$$ := '1341';
    with
    TIME_DATA  as ( select $$D:=DA$$; td from dual),
    GROUP_INFO as (select $$N:=:GR_ID$$ gr_id_number from dual),
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C# you can do this:

```
// using Oracle.DataAccess.Client
using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(commandText, dbConnection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("DA$$", OracleDbType.Int32, valueDA, ParameterDirection.Input);
    command.Parameters.Add("GR_ID$$", OracleDbType.Int32, valueGR_ID, ParameterDirection.Input);
}
```

But review your comand text. Because you will probably face syntax errors due to "$$D:" and "$$N:"