# How to declare a Date variable in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Server I do the following way

DECLARE @Date DATE

SELECT @Date=Max(date) from table1

Final Out put

SELECT * FROM Table2
WHERE date=@Date

But in the same way in ORACLE PL/SQL(Esp in SQL Developer ) , How can I declare the Variable?

Advise and help please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use variables in Oracle SQL Developer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653423/how-do-i-use-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: Can I have the syntax specifically for DATE datatype.

Comment: `variable var DATE`
`exec :var := '02-APR-2015'`

Comment: Thank You SQL User. Problem here is I need the date to get dynamically like variable var DATE exec :var := select max(date) from table