# Use a variable in a basic select in Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

I come from a sql server background.  Frequently when trying to build some reports or answer questions from the database I would write queries that use a variable several times within the query. Rather than update the value 3-4 times each time I want to change the query I would use a variable so I can update the value only once.  For brevity I have written a simple query below that illustrates what I would do in SQL Server when trying to pull a report.

```
declare @test numeric(3)
select @test = 683
select myColumn from myTable where myColumn = @test
```

What is the equivalent of this in oracle?  I tried to write something similar but got some error messages about requiring an into statement.  From what I can gather you can select something into a variable in oracle but you cant use a variable in a read only fashion like I have done above.  Is it even possible to write a query similar to the one above in oracle?

Comment: Look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12017.htm.  Please note that this only really works interactively.  Programmatically there are other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Declare:**

```
SQL> variable x number
```

**Assign:**

```
SQL> begin :x := 3; end;
  2  /
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Use:**

```
SQL> select :x from dual;
        :X
----------
         3
1 row selected.
```

Note: In Oracle, : is used instead of @, as in  :x instead of @x;  and the assignment operator is :=, not =.

Comment: Ive seen a number of oracle questions have their answer include this SQL> before the script.  I am using sql navigator and I don't have anything like that prepending lines of query langauge.  Do I actually need to type out SQL> ?

Comment: No, you don't. That is the console prompt if you use SQL*Plus, Oracle's simplest client-side interface to the database. You don't need the prompt if you write your queries in SQL Developer, Toad, etc.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when I run that in sql navigator, but the result of the query is a blank column, not the number.  I suspect this might be issue with sql navigator or the installation, not the query though :-/

Comment: Uhm... sorry, I think "variable x number" is a SQL*Plus command. I am not familiar with SQL Navigator; someone who uses it may be able to help.

Comment: See if the reply in this old threat at Toadworld helps: https://www.toadworld.com/products/sql-navigator/f/51/t/4583

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Developer, write the query and use for variables ':'

```
select myColumn from myTable where myColumn = :test
```

When you start (Ctrl-Enter) the query, the SQL Developer will ask for the value of :test.

If you want to change the select statement dynamically, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653423/how-do-i-use-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer) answer:

```
define value1 = 'sysdate+3 as mydate';
SELECT &&value1 from dual;
```