# ORACLE: "Missing right parenthesis" error when using variables

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I have a very long Oracle SQL script that filters for article numbers in multiple places, i.e.:

```
[...]
where article_nr = 12345
[...]
```

To avoid adjusting 20 lines of code manually when changing the article, I introduced variables, i.e.:

```
define article_1 = 12345
[...]
where article_nr = &&article_1
[...]
```

Now, however, I get an error saying that it's "missing right parenthesis". I did not touch anything regarding a parenthesis, just replaced the 12345 by the variable.
Do I have to escape the "&&" somehow?

Sorry for not posting the full code, but its multiple nested selects.

Thanks

EDIT (Working example):

This works:

```
select * from stores
where
   (opening_date >= '21.11.2016')
;
```

This DOESN'T works (either with one or with two "&"):

```
define opening = '21.11.2016'

select * from stores
where
   (opening_date >= &&opening)
;
```

==> "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: Why did you put 2 &? To use parameters you should either write :article_1 or &article_1 depending on your context.

Comment: I followed this guide: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653423/how-do-i-use-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: PS: Even with only one "&", I get the same error

Comment: in one of the comments of [the answer where the define is used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14333561/7170434) in your link, they say you have to surround `&&article_1` with single quotes when using it to compare values: `'&&article_1'`

Comment: [This link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/sub-var2-099853.html) says the same.

Comment: As an aside, what is the datatype of the opening_date column? If it's DATE then you should really be converting your string-representing-a-date into a date, either by using the ANSI `DATE 'yyyy-mm-dd'` literal, or by using `to_date('<your date string>', '<date format of your date string>')`. Also, if your opening_date column is a VARCHAR2 column, your comparison is not going to return the right results. After all, '22.01.2016' is greater than '21.11.2016', yet 22nd Jan 2016 is definitely before 21st Nov 2016!

Answer (score 0):

Numeric literals do not require quote marks ...

```
where article_nr = 12345
```

but date (and string) literals do ...

```
(opening_date >= '21.11.2016')
```

The same rules apply for substitution variables. Numeric assignment:

```
where article_nr = &&article_1
```

Date assignment:

```
(opening_date >= '&&opening')
```

As others have commented, it's good practice to explicitly cast dates:

```
(opening_date >= to_date('&&opening', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))
```