# How to define and use global variable in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dynamic-queries

I'm a tester and I have to run lots of select queries to filter out the information I'm testing.

[image]

Is there a way to make global variable and use it instead of pasting same values?

[image]

Sample code:

```
Select l.prod_package,m.* from avtt7m0 m, avtt7l0 l 
where l.cust_id='52317162090004' 
and l.ar_id=m.ar_id and m.lc_st_code='ACT'; 

Select m.* from avtt7m0 m, avtt7l0 l 
where l.cust_id='52317162090004' 
and l.ar_id=m.ar_id and m.lc_st_code='ACT'; 

Select * From AKTTD90 
where cust_id in ('52317162090004'); 

Select * From Kndt7m0 
where cust_id in ('52317162090004');
```

Comment: You can use a t-sql variable and set it beforehand. If you post the code you are using instead of a picture I'll show you how to use it

Comment: Which dbms are you using. (The answer will probably be product specific.)

Comment: I'm using SQL developer. Here is the code : Select l.prod_package,m.* from avtt7m0 m, avtt7l0 l where l.cust_id='52317162090004' and l.ar_id=m.ar_id and m.lc_st_code='ACT'; 

Select m.* from avtt7m0 m, avtt7l0 l where l.cust_id='52317162090004' and l.ar_id=m.ar_id and m.lc_st_code='ACT'; 

Select * From AKTTD90 where cust_id in ('52317162090004');  

Select * From Kndt7m0 where cust_id in ('52317162090004');

Comment: How about I post it in the question for you. There that wasn't too hard

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653423/how-do-i-use-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable and assign it the `customer` value.

```
DECLARE @Customer BIGINT='52371762090004'

SELECT * FROM AKTTD90 WHERE Cust_id=@Customer
```

**UPDATE:** Try executing the above query.

Comment: It is not working. Im using SQL developer 4.1 can it bet the cause ? I don't know much about SQL querys. So it can be that I don't give all information for you to help me. But I will try answer if I can.

Comment: @VItas i have updated the answer. Do Check.

Comment: It gives an error. Do you know what can be wrong ? Error starting at line 1 in command:
DECLARE @Customer BIGINT='52371762090004'
SELECT * FROM KNDT7L0 WHERE cust_id =@Customer
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: That's T-SQL syntax not oracle syntax

Answer (score 0):

This aims at SQL Server - your question doesn't have a specific RDMS.  You can `Declare` a variable (which must begin with `@` then `Set` it then use it (in most cases):

```
SET @CustomerID = 12345
SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID
```

Note that this cannot be used for certain things, such as a variable for a table name.  Also note that these variables are not actually Global in the sense that they will not survive a `GO` statement.

Comment: It seems SQL developer 4.1 do not like this syntax. Sory if I didn't gave all info. It's just becouse I'm new at SQL so I don't know what's important to mention.

Comment: edited for mysql/sql developer.  that should work now (the declare portion isn't required for mysql).

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this is with PL/SQL-Package Variables:

```
create or replace package steptest as
  procedure set(a number);
  function get return number;
end;
/

create or replace package body steptest as
  x number;
  procedure set(a number) is
  begin
    x:=a;
  end;
  function get return number is
  begin
    return x;
  end;
begin
  x:=0;
end;    
/
```

And then you can:

```
exec steptest.set(1234);

select steptest.get from dual;
```