# Oracle PL/SQL - Bind Variables Basic Issue - ORA-00900

Tags: oracle, plsql, bind-variables

I am trying to use BIND variables in Oracle SQL Developer, but each time I execute I got

> ORA-00900 'Invalid SQL statement" Error.

Here is my code:

```
VARIABLE v_bind1 NUMBER;
```

Here is error that I get:
https://s27.postimg.org/edqqt2mhv/bind_variable_problem.jpg

Oracle Database 11g 11.2.0.4.0

PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0

Oracle SQL Developer 1.5.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use variables in Oracle SQL Developer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653423/how-do-i-use-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: Nothing wrong with the statement. The version of SQL Developer is way too old. [Download latest one, which is 4.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but DECALRE SQL*Plus function should be supported by 1.5.5 : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/sql-worksheet-commands-097146.html. Also I have the same problem with, for example EXECUTE function

Comment: Do you see any mentionings of `DECLARE` or `EXECUTE` in your original question?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found out the problem.
I was using command *Execute Statement (F9).*
In order for SQL*Plus command to work I should use *Run Script (F5)*