# How can I get table column value to defined variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

How do I get the table column value to the defined variable? This is the code I tested:

```sh
 DEFINE R_EXPIRY_DAYS = '';
 SELECT NVL(EXPIRY_DAYS_AFTER,30) INTO R_EXPIRY_DAYS FROM USER_TABLE;
```

Comment: Does this help: [How do I use variables in Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653423/how-do-i-use-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer/22171706)

Comment: what error occurs when you execute?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE R_EXPIRY_DAYS  VARCHAR2(64);

BEGIN
   SELECT my_column INTO R_EXPIRY_DAYS FROM USER_TABLE;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, why would you use a substitution variable for that?

- `DEFINE` explicitly creates a substitution variable
- `VARIABLE` declares a bind variable you can use in PL/SQL - that's what I'd use, which is also suggested by `INTO R_EXPIRY_DAYS` you posted - `into` means PL/SQL.

---

```
SQL> select * from user_table;

EXPIRY_DAYS_AFTER
-----------------
               20

SQL> var r_expiry_days number
SQL> exec select nvl(expiry_days_after,30) into :r_expiry_days from user_table;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print r_expiry_days

R_EXPIRY_DAYS
-------------
           20

SQL>
```

---

If you insist on a substitution variable and want to store result of the `select` statement into it, then you don't use `define` but `column` with `new_value`:

```
SQL> column exp_days_aft new_value r_expiry_days
SQL> select nvl(expiry_days_after, 30) exp_days_aft from user_table;

EXP_DAYS_AFT
------------
          20

SQL> define r_expiry_days
DEFINE R_EXPIRY_DAYS   =         20 (NUMBER)
SQL>
```

Right; `r_expiry_days` really contains `20`.